# WordPress Not rendering short code properly?

Tags: shortcode

So I have other short codes that are built in this fashion and I cant figure out what i did between them and this one, This short code is used as such: `[code code="function(){}"]` to wrap your input in `<code></code>` tags, great for something super simple.

the issue is:

```
function aisis_inline_code($atts, $content = null){
    extract (
        shortcode_atts (
            array (
                'code' => 'test?'
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );  
    return '<code>'.$code.'</code>';
}

add_shortcode( 'code', 'aisis_inline_code');
```

The above renders out `test` wrapped in code tags instead of the content I put in which is: `[code code="function(){}"]`

How do we debug these? This was working pre WordPress 3.7.1, not it seems all it wants to do is out put `test?`. I checked the spelling of the short code spelling a hundred times. ...

Comment: a copy/paste of your code and example shortcode work as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your solution (copy and paste) and it is working fine in Wordpress 3.7.1 Maybe check your post again. Can you provide a link to your site?
(can not comment yet, thats why I answer)

Comment: @TheWebs It works fine for me too tested in Wordpress 3.7.1